# Recaptcha connection timeout on the linux server

Tags: java, linux, captcha, recaptcha

I am using [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for captcha on my website. It runs all right when I run it on a localhost server. But when I am running it on a linux server, it gives me connection time out message. I am not sure why ? 
 
I see that many people have had the same issue, but no resolution does anyone know what might be the issue ? I am using the Java example given in the documentation.

here it is -> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java

```
net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaException: Cannot load URL: Connection timed out
    at net.tanesha.recaptcha.http.SimpleHttpLoader.httpPost(SimpleHttpLoader.java:89)
```

My iptable settings for port 80 are :

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried to curl

```
 http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify
```

from the web server and it did not allow. I guess the host is not reachable from the server. How to allow post/get from the linux server to the google api website ?

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code" :)

Comment: I have used the same code as in the example on Recaptcha. here it is -> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java

Comment: @JiriKremser what do u think ?

Comment: well, if even curl can't reach the URL then the problem is in your IP tables settings. Try this: SERVER_IP=w.x.y.z"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d $SERVER_IP --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 80 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: btw. do you use your own api key?

Comment: Yes I do use my API key, I have ran it well locally the problem was on remote. I will keep you posted about things

Comment: I knew about this command but how can we find the server ip ? i will keep on changing i think

Comment: `ifconfig` will tell you the server ip address or `ip addr show`. Try also simple `ping www.google.com` from that server

Comment: Did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

1). Error in Your INPUT chain:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Here must be **--sport** not **--dport**. Because curl may use any port for new output request and will be waiting response on it. For example 44254 or any other.

2). May it will be necessary to add also similar rule for 443 port, because new version of Google RECaptcha use it by default.